# Number of patients

Tags: functions

At a doctor's clinic patients arrive at an average rate of 10 per hour. The consultancy time per patient is exponentially distributed with an average of 6 minutes per patient. The doctor does not admit any patient if at any time 10 patients are waiting. Then at the steady state of this M/M/1/R queue the expected number of patients waiting is ?

I tried exponential distribution. But I do not know how it works.
Please help.

Comment: What does M/M/1/R means?

Comment: why don't you use Little's law? 6  minutes is 1/10 of an hour, so 10*0.01 = 1 customer is on average waiting

Comment: @FFjet Quick search on queue theory ("mm1r queue") led me to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_notation).

Comment: @Arthur I see. Thx ;D

Comment: @Steven31415 To apply Little's law, you have to consider the average time in the system, which includes time in the queue as well as time being served.

Comment: thanks saulspatz for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Look at Section 2.4 [here](https://irh.inf.unideb.hu/~jsztrik/education/16/SOR_Main_Angol.pdf)  The inter-arrival time equals the service time, so we have $\rho=1.$  The system is therefore equally likely to have any number of patients from $0$ to $11$.  Notice that when there are $0$ or $1$ patients, there is no one in the waiting room.  So if $p_k$ is the steady-state probability that there are $k$ patients in the waiting room, we have $$p_k=\cases{\frac16,&$k=0$\\{1\over12},&$1\leq k\leq10$\\0,&$k>10$}$$